# How do I change this algorithm to incorporate multiple particles in the random walk rather than just one particle?

Tags: fortran

What do I do to add multiple particles to the program below? It is just a simple random walk in 3 dimensions.

```
program RW3D

    implicit none

    integer :: x, y, z, i
    real :: P

    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

    do i = 1, 100
       call random_number (p)

        write (1,*) i, x, y, z

        if (p .lt. 1.0/6) then
            x = x - 1
         else if (p .gt. 1.0/6 .lt. 2.0/6) then
            y = y - 1
         else if (p .lt. 3.0/6) then
            z = z - 1
         else if (p .lt. 4.0/6) then
            x = x + 1
         else if (p .lt. 5.0/6) then
            y = y + 1
         else
            z = z + 1
        end if

    end do

end program RW3D
```

Comment: You have a perfectly decent answer, but there's truly a lot more to consider when modelling multiple particles (than what is effectively running the program multiple times): do the particles interact; where do they start; is there a constant stepping time?  (etc.)

Comment: Your comparison operators hurt my eyes. Why not write `a < b` instead of (ugly) `a .lt. b`?

Answer (score 2):

Most simple approach: create arrays

```
   integer, parameter :: n = ...the number of particles

   integer :: x(n), y(n), z(n)
   integer :: i, j
```

.....

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

do i = 1, 100
  do j = 1, n
   call random_number (p)

    if (p .lt. 1.0/6) then
        x(j) = x(j) - 1
     else if (p .gt. 1.0/6 .lt. 2.0/6) then
        y(j) = y(j) - 1
```

and so on.

Other approach is to create derived type for particles

```
type particle
  integer :: x, y, z
end type
```

and an array of them

```
type(particle) :: particles(n)
```

I have shown static arrays of size `n`. Of course you can use allocatable arrays.

I didn't include any input/output because you must decide how to store your results.

I don't recommend using unit number `1` in `write(1,*)`. Units below 10 are often used for special purposes. Use numbers above 10. Best is to use the `newunit=` from Fortran 2008.